# Large searchable and sortable table with custom fields

Tags: database, performance, laravel, architecture, database-optimization

I have some large tables in a MySQL database (in the order of ~100,000 rows). I'm attempting to optimize a web application front-end which allows the searching, sorting and filtering of values computed from these tables. These values are of various types - obtained through joins and some semi-complex calculations.

What are some best practices/common design patterns for this type of problem? My main concerns are code readability as well as performance. I'm using the PHP framework Laravel and have forsaken Eloquent (its ORM) in order to squeeze some extra speed out of it by doing everything in a single raw SQL query - however this is far less readable and not ideal. It's also still not fast enough. I have indexed all columns involved in calculations, joins and where statements as well as implementing paged results.

Comment: Did you analyse the query plan of executed SQL? I know for oracle but not mysql, you can find a tool to analyse the SQL query execution plan, check if query plan is going through indexes, if not add any hints. If still big split into 2 small queries and union or process in the code..

Comment: Start by running your query with EXPLAIN to see if it uses any indexes and if there are any subqueries. Note that MySQL can only use one index for each sub-part of a query so make sure you include all relevant fields in the same index.

Comment: anything below 1 million is hardly big in SQL world but to start page your results. Nothing is worst than returning 100k rows to the user

Comment: Well, even a problem with a few thousand rows can be grow fast if you join without relevant keys. Joining two tables with 3k rows each can mean considering 3000^2 = 9 million combinations! That's why you need to analyze the problem with EXPLAIN. The problem size is (in most cases) given by multiplying the numbers in the `rows`  column of the EXPLAIN output.